# Changing a logical operator from TRUE to FALSE after a number of candles in Pine Script

Tags: variables, pine-script

In Tradingview, I’d like to check “Super Trend” and “QQE MOD” indicators to create Buy/Sell signals.

When super trend turned from RED to GREEN, I’m checking if QQE Mode indicator has green bars as well. And I have no issue doing this

Here is the tricky part: This strategy works far more efficiently if QQE mode indicator bars turned to green Maximum 3 candles back when super trend turned to green. If QQE MOD turned to green 10 candles before super trend’s first green signal, then it does not work.

I created a variable which becomes “true” when QQE mod  bar turns to green. I want to make it "false" after 3 candles. (no other conditions needed. when the 3rd candle closes after it turns to true, I need it to turn itself to false automatically)

But I don’t know how to change a variable from true to false or from false to true after a specific number of candles or time.

Which function should I use for this?

I would appreciate if you can help.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ta.barssince()` function for that.

```
if ta.barssince(yourCondition) == 3 //three candles after your condition
    yourVariable := false
```

Comment: Wauww, that was fast :) Thank you so much...